# Coloring flash symbols with two objects

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs3

Hey Folks, I am a newbie to Illustrator and flash. Here I have two objects; background and highlight. Highlight has a certain amount a opacity set to it 45%, so it appears lighter then the background. I want to color just the background in as3/flash builder 4, but when I color the flash symbol, the highlight region also gets colored and I don't want to do that. I also don't want to have two separate symbols, because then I'll have to add more code and variables.

Is there any way to color just the background and let the highlight object just be?

[image: http://imgur.com/ezH1E]

I hope I've conveyed myself well.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to segment your object into two parts - most likely the background on a lower layer and the highlight on the higher. Then give your background an instance name and change the colour of only that.

I don't see why you would need more code for this, your object will still be one, just made up of two children (ie your arrow or whatever that is will still be a single arrow, with a the background as one of the children that you can access and modify).

EG:

```
var col:ColorTransform = your_object.background.transform.colorTransform;
col.color = 0xFF0000;
your_object.background.transform.colorTransform = col;
```

Comment: Hey thanx for responding.
If i set only the background as the symbol, then the flex is not even picking up the highlight part.
The real problem is with the Flash only, can you please explain me how to save a graphic with a symbol and a another graphic (highlight).

PS. Ya i know about the acceptance thingy, i did some work just now.